# Redefine array based on a column in child array column value - PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have a following **ModulePermissions** Array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [module_permission_index_id] => 347
            [module_id] => 1
            [user_id] => 29
            [can_view] => 1
            [can_edit] => 1
            [can_add] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [module_permission_index_id] => 348
            [module_id] => 2
            [user_id] => 29
            [can_view] => 1
            [can_edit] => 1
            [can_add] => 1
        )
   ... ... ...
)
```

**Target**:

Now I want to get Array to be sorted based on their module (module Id has multiple permissions)
something like below (please ignore syntax and get the idea)

```
   [1] => array(
       array(
            [module_permission_index_id] => 347
            [user_id] => 29
            [can_view] => 1
            [can_edit] => 1
            [can_add] => 1
       )
   )
   [2] => array(
       array(
            [module_permission_index_id] => 348
            [user_id] => 29
            [can_view] => 1
            [can_edit] => 1
            [can_add] => 1
       )
   )
   ... ... ...
)
```

Is there any way PHP helps do this?

Comment: Have you made any progress with this yourself?

Comment: @NigelRen
so far the following did the trick
foreach ($modulePermissionsDb as $permission) {
          $modulePermissions[$permission['module_id']] = $permission;
      }

Comment: but I waas wondering for a more elegent solution rather that creating a new array using loop

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is:

```
$newData = [];
foreach ($yourData as $item) {
    $newData[$item['module_id']][] = $item;
}
```